# Creating an event that prevents similar inputs from triggering the same event

Tags: python

I am having difficulty making the code stop from triggering the same event. It is in this layout because I needed to learn which entry box the input originated from so that I can write a code to create a warning system. I am willing to change the entire code if needed to be.

`current output: 3x \n a_entry`

`output wanted: a_entry, b_entry, c_entry`

```py
def input_origin(user_input):
    if user_input == raw_user_inputs[0]:
        print("a_entry")

            

    elif user_input == raw_user_inputs[1]:
        print("b_entry")
 
    elif user_input == raw_user_inputs[2]:
        print("c_entry")

    else:
        print(user_input, "origin is unknown")

raw_user_inputs = ["1", "1", "1"]

for number in raw_user_inputs:

    input_origin(number)
```

Comment: `3x \n a_entry` can't be the out put, where would `3x` come from? I ran this code and the output is `a_entry \n a_entry \n a_entry`

Comment: Sorry I mistyped the output, the 3x meant 
a_entry
a_entry 
a_entry
sorry that I didn't label it this way

Answer (score 0):

You need to `set()` the inputs.

```py
def input_origin(user_input):
    if user_input == unique_set_of_inputs[0]:
        print("a_entry")

            

    elif user_input == unique_set_of_inputs[1]:
        print("b_entry")
 
    elif user_input == unique_set_of_inputs[2]:
        print("c_entry")

    else:
        print(user_input, "origin is unknown")

raw_user_inputs = ["1", "2", "3", "1", "2"]
unique_set_of_inputs = list(set(raw_user_inputs))
for number in unique_set_of_inputs:

    input_origin(number)
```

prints:

```
a_entry
b_entry
c_entry
```

Comment: thanks for your time I will use that method as well

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to solve this. I created a counter variable that counts

```
def input_origin(user_input):
    if user_input == raw_user_inputs[0] and counter == 0:
        print("a_entry")

            

    elif user_input == raw_user_inputs[1] and counter == 1:
        print("b_entry")
 
    elif user_input == raw_user_inputs[2] and counter == 2:
        print("c_entry")

    else:
        print(user_input, "origin is unknown")

raw_user_inputs = ["1", "1", "1"]

counter = 0

for number in raw_user_inputs:

    input_origin(number)
    counter = counter + 1
```

please let me know if this is a bad way of doing it